# Decoding RTSP stream from camera using NVIDIA's VIDEO SDK

Tags: c++, video, rtsp, decoding

I am trying to use the CUDA support in NVIDIA's Video Codec SDK to read frames from a RTSP camera. The standard examples don't seem to understand the "url" as OpenCV does. Is there a different means to have the Codec use the RTSP url and stream in the data?

Failing that, they do describe that there is a clean separation so that other input methods can feed into their decoders, but the only FileProvider I have found so far is one that reads a file alone.  Has anyone used this method of feeding their Demuxer?

```
    FFmpegDemuxer demuxer(szInFilePath);
    NvDecoder dec(cuContext, false, FFmpeg2NvCodecId(demuxer.GetVideoCodec()), false, false, &cropRect, &resizeDim);
```

Comment: This question is quite unclear, and the small code snippet does not help. The chief thing I'd note is that RTSP is not used to stream video frames. RTSP is typically used to negotiate an RTP stream.

Comment: The camera uses a url "rtsp://user:pwd@192.168.1.xxx:80/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0" string to provide video data.  Using this in openCV produces a video stream that can have frames extracted.  Using this same technique in the CUDA example gives an error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.